# Set ProxySelector and Authenticator back to their default

Tags: java, proxy, osgi, dynamic-proxy

I was tasked to write a custom [ProxySelector](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html) implementation for our current OSGi project. In order to use authentication for proxies I also had to write a custom [Authenticator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html).

Setting these custom implementations when the OSGi bundle starts works great. But OSGi bundles can be stopped/uninstalled which brings me to my question:

**How do I unset my implementations and restore the default (JVM) implementations?**

While the bundle starts I save the default implementation:

```
ProxySelector defaultSelector = ProxySelector.getDefault()
ProxySelector.setDefault(new MyProxySelector());
```

Sadly Authenticator does not have an `getDefault()` method.

When the bundle is stopping I want to unset ProxySelector and Authenticator like so:

```
ProxySelector.setDefault(defaultSelector); // see above
Authenticator.setDefault(null);
```

But this doesn't work. After the bundle stops I can't make any connections.

My only explanation is that setting the `defaultSelector` is only passing a reference. When my ProxySelector is destroyed these reference points nowhere thus causing the JVM to have no valid ProxySelector. The best solution I came up was to clone the selector. But ProxySelector does not have a `clone()` method. Casting the `defaultSelector` to some default implementation (*sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector*) might not be the best solution but could work. It could be a problem because it could override other custom implementations that have been set before.

**So what is your best practice for this?**